# Each method in Ruby not working as I expected

Tags: ruby

I have two inputs and I am trying to print the first one but if any of those elements on the second array is the same than any of the elements of the second array it should print the word "REDACTED" instead of that element. But I'm not having the expected result

**input 1** `a b c d`
**input 2** `a c`

**expected result** `REDACTED b REDACTED d` but **my result** is this `REDACTED b REDACTED c c d d`

```rb
puts "Enter some text: "
text = gets.chomp

puts "Enter words to redact: "
redact = gets.chomp

words_text = text.split(" ")
words_redact = redact.split(" ")

words_text.each do |word|
  words_redact.each do |r_word|
    if word == r_word
      print "REDACTED "
      break
    else
      print word + " "
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: There’s nothing wrong with `each`, the problem is with your if/else logic.  Trace through by hand for your sample input to see why you get duplicated outputs. You might consider replacing the second loop with `words_redact.include? word`

Comment: Hint: You should only `print word…` after you’ve failed to match **all** of the redacted words.

Comment: Adding duplicate items in the redacted list will also give you a big clue.

Comment: Try `words_text.each do |word| if words_redact.include?(word) .... end`. See [Array#include?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-include-3F).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Others are quite correct that using `#include?` is the best way to address this, but you *can* iterate over the redacted words array to check each word. We set a flag called `should_be_redacted` to `false`, then iterate over `words_redact`. If any of those words equals the word we're looking for, we change `should_be_redacted` to `true`, and `break` to avoid doing unnecessary work.

Then we simply need to decide what to print based on the value of `should_be_redacted`.

```rb
words_text.each do |word|
  should_be_redacted = false

  words_redact.each do |r_word|
    if word == r_word
      should_be_redacted = true
      break
    end
  end

  print "#{should_be_redacted ? 'REDACTED' : word} "
end
```

You may wish to compare in a case-insentive way.

```rb
words_text.each do |word|
  should_be_redacted = false

  words_redact.each do |r_word|
    if word.upcase == r_word.upcase
      should_be_redacted = true
      break
    end
  end

  print "#{should_be_redacted ? 'REDACTED' : word} "
end
```

We can simplify using the `#any?` method to handle the short-circuiting for us and the boolean value.

```rb
words_text.each do |word|
  should_be_redacted = 
    words_redact.any? do |r_word|
      word.upcase == r_word.upcase
    end

  print "#{should_be_redacted ? 'REDACTED' : word} "
end
```

Comment: Since you already have a variable holding the current word, you could just re-assign it: `word = 'REDACTED' if word == r_word`

Comment: That's a great suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with 2 each, you have 2 loops and if for each occurence you print at least `print word + " "`.
A better approch would be to use include? and loop through a single array.

```
result = words_text.map do |word|
    if words_redact.include? word
        "REDACTED"
    else
        word
    end
end

print result
```

Comment: This will not redact anything it will simply print `words_text` because `each` returns the receiver (e.g. `result.equal?(words_text) #=> true`). Maybe you were looking for `map`?

Comment: You're right I forget to add map. Thank you @engineersmnky. I copied the first line from the question and forgot to update it.